# Swift error Cannot convert value of type '(AFHTTPRequestOperation?, AnyObject?) -> ()

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, afhttprequestoperation

After I update xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a) swift 3, I got this error

Cannot convert value of type '(AFHTTPRequestOperation?, AnyObject?) -> ()' to expected argument type '((AFHTTPRequestOperation?, Any?) -> Void)!'

This is the following code that's shown error above.

```
jsonmanager.post( "http://myapi.com",
                      parameters: nil,
                      success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                        if(responseObject.object(forKey: "meta")?.object(forKey: "status")?.intValue == 200){....
```

Am i doing something wrong ?

It works well in previous version 7.3.1 swift 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callback method signature has changed. In Swift 2 it was

```
(AFHTTPRequestOperation?, AnyObject?) -> Void
```

In Swift 3 it's

```
(AFHTTPRequestOperation?, Any?) -> Void
```

You should  change the line below

```
success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!)
```

To

```
success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?, responseObject: Any?)
```

Comment: After i changed i got this message : Cannot call value of non-function type 'Any?!'

Comment: And this inside if : Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'object'

Comment: You could try to cast the `responseObject` to `AnyObject`. `AnyObject` and `Any` are pretty different so you're going to have to rewrite that par of your app to properly handle `Any` instead of `AnyObject`